# phpmyAdmin gives error while database and tables look good in mySQL CLI

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I changed a name of the table from within phpMyAdmin, and immediately it crapped. after that when I try to connect using phpMyAdmin (/phpMyAdmin/index.php) I get error in log:

```
[Wed Aug 08 14:18:58 2012] [error] Query call failed: Table 'mydb.mychangedtbl' doesn't exist (1146)
```

mychangedtbl is the table whose name was changed. this issue is only in phpMyAdmin, I am able to access the database and tables find from CLI. I restarted mySQL, but that did not fix. Seems like something is stuck for phpMyAdmin. I restarted browser also but that didnt help either.

when i rename this particular table back to what it was using command line, myphphAmin works fine again. here is the structure of this table:

```
    mysql> DESCRIBE mychangedtbl;
    +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | userid    | char(6)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    | userpass  | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | userlevel | char(3)     | NO   |     | o       |       |
    | userpcip  | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

column userpass has Collation = asci_bin which it does not show in above output, other columns are ascii_general_ci

pl advice.

ty.
Rajeev

Answer (score 0):

this was due to the reason that, apache was using the same table to do mysql authentication. i changed apache config and restart. that let me change table name. all good again.